# How do I get both functions to work at once in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, weekday

I'm really new to all this and right now I'm trying to get two functions to perform and print, but I can't seem to grasp it:

```
import datetime  

def get_date(prompt):
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input(prompt)  
        try:

            user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%m-%d")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print "There was an error:", e
            print "Please enter a date"
    return user_date.date()

def checkNight(date):
    date = datetime.strptime('2011-'+date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('$A')

birthday = get_date("Please enter your birthday (MM-DD): ")
another_date = get_date("Please enter another date (MM-DD): ")

if birthday > another_date:
    print "Your friend's birthday comes first!"
    print checkNight(date)

elif birthday < another_date:
    print "Your birthday comes first!"
    print checkNight(date)

else:  
    print "You and your friend can celebrate together."
```

The function `get_date` needs to be able to check that the date has 5 characters and allows the split to be anything. Also if someone would type "02-29", it would treat it as "02-28". `checkNight` needs to be able to check what night the earlier birthday falls upon.

Here are some examples:

```
Please enter your birthday (MM-DD): 11-25
Please enter a friend's birthday (MM-DD): 03-05
Your friend's birthday comes first!
Great!  The party is on Saturday, a weekend night.

Please enter your birthday (MM-DD): 03-02
Please enter a friend's birthday (MM-DD): 03-02
You and your friend can celebrate together!
Too bad!  The party is on Wednesday, a school night.

Please enter your birthday (MM-DD): 11-25
Please enter a friend's birthday (MM-DD): 12-01
Your birthday comes first!
Great!  The party is on Friday, a weekend night.
```

Comment: Write down what you'd like do to but can't express in code. Without that, it's not a question but a task description.

Comment: I'd recommend a python tutorial to get you started http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Answer (score 2):

- One error is due to calling `checkNight(date)` without the variable "date" having been defined.
- `datetime.strptime` should read `datetime.datetime.strptime`.
- The concatenation of a string and a date in that same line (`'2011-'+date`) might also cause an error.
- The `checkNight(date)` function is not returning anything
- Etc.

Maybe this is a little closer to what you want:

```
import datetime  

def get_date(prompt):
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input(prompt)  
        try:
            user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%m-%d")
            user_date = user_date.replace(year=2011)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print "There was an error:", e
            print "Please enter a date"
    return user_date

def checkNight(date):
    return date.strftime('%A')

birthday = get_date("Please enter your birthday (MM-DD): ")
another_date = get_date("Please enter another date (MM-DD): ")

if birthday > another_date:
    print "Your friend's birthday comes first!"
    print checkNight(another_date)

elif birthday < another_date:
    print "Your birthday comes first!"
    print checkNight(birthday)

else:  
    print "You and your friend can celebrate together."
```

Note that since I change the year for 2011 right after the user inputs it, I can extract the day of the week more simply in `checkNight()`.